# Creating Custom Call out View

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm trying to add a view when I click in a pin, but appears only the title and subtitle and not the view that I did add.

Here is my code

```
  -(void) inserirMapa {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSMutableArray *pins = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //array de Annotations
    for(int iCnt = 0; iCnt < [_listaPins count]; iCnt++) {
        Pin *pin = (Pin *) [_listaPins objectAtIndex:iCnt];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D start;
        start.latitude = pin.place.latitude;
        start.longitude = pin.place.longitude;
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(start, 800, 800);
        [_myMapView setRegion:[_myMapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

        // Add an annotation
        MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        point.coordinate = start;
        point.title = @"Where am I?";
        point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";

        [_myMapView addAnnotation:point];

        [pins addObject:point];//adiciona a annotation no array
        [point release];
    }
    self.myAnnotations= [NSArray arrayWithArray:pins]; //diz que o array myAnnotations é igual ao array estacionamentos(que contem as annotations
        [pins release];
        [self configurarZoomDoMapaComLatitude:appDelegate.latitude eLongitude:appDelegate.longitude]; //configura o Zoom inicial do mapa


    [_myMapView addAnnotations:_myAnnotations];

    [_viewLoading setHidden:YES];
}
```

and here I add the custom view. I put a breakpoint here and this function is called, but when I click in a pin, appearas only the title and subtitle..ignoring the view that I added

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = nil;

    //your code

    UIView *vw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    vw.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50)];
    label.numberOfLines = 4;
    label.text = @"hello\nhow are you\nfine";
    [vw addSubview:label];
    annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = vw;
    return annotationView;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `viewForAnnotation`, the code declares and initializes `annotationView` to `nil` and never actually instantiates it (alloc+init).

Therefore, the delegate method returns `nil` which tells the map view to "create the default view for this annotation".  The default view for an annotation other than the user location is a red pin with a callout that only shows the title and subtitle.

However, if you just alloc+init a plain `MKAnnotationView` to fix it, the annotations will not be visible since by default an `MKAnnotationView` has no content.  You would need to set its `image` or add some subview.

Instead, you could alloc+init an `MKPinAnnotationView` which by default will show a red pin.
You should also implement annotation view re-use by calling `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` to improve performance when there are lots of annotations:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *reuseId = @"ann";

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView 
        dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                                 initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                    reuseIdentifier:@"test"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;  //set to YES, default is NO

        //your code

        UIView *vw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        vw.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50)];
        label.numberOfLines = 4;
        label.text = @"hello\nhow are you\nfine";
        [vw addSubview:label];
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = vw;
    }
    else
    {
        //Update view's annotation reference 
        //because we are re-using view that may have
        //been previously used for another annotation...
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return annotationView;
}
```

This should fix the custom `leftCalloutAccessoryView` not appearing.
However, note what the documentation says for the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` (and `rightCalloutAccessoryView`):

> The height of your view should be 32 pixels or less.

The custom view and label the code is creating are both more than 32 pixels high.

An unrelated comment regarding the loop that adds the annotations:
You do not need to call `setRegion` as you are adding each annotation.
Calling `setRegion` just tells the map view to display the indicated region.
That is not needed to add an annotation (the map doesn't have to be displaying the coordinate you are adding the annotation at).

Comment: Thx, it works. But how can I create a bigger view? I need that appear a view 100 x100 with ImageViews, label and buttons when click in pin. Its possible?

Comment: I did found this [example code](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/) example code that use a custom Annotation View.

Comment: The built-in callout view is not very customizable as you saw.  Only approach is to disable it (canShowCallout=NO) and in didSelectAnnotationView, add your custom callout view to the annotation view itself (that's one approach).  The example code you found seems to be one popular option.

Comment: Yes, my question was why the acessoryview didn't appear...and you answered perfectly, therefore I did mark your answer as correct. But what I really wanted was the custom callout view. Thx for help!