# Tapping om MKAnnotationView should show my custom view

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Tapping on `MKAnnotationView` shouldn't show the callout view, instead it should show my custom view covering 3/4 of the iPhone's screen. I'm hiding the native callout view by `canShowCalloutView = NO`, but how to detect tap on that `MKAnnotationView` and then present my custom pop-up view? I guess i should implement `didSelectAnnotationView` and then show my custom view?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set canShowCalloutView to Yes and         annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = yourView;

Please refer below link to understand how to set custom callout view:

[Creating Custom Call out View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863565/creating-custom-call-out-view)

Comment: My initial request was not to show that callout view, instead directly to show my own custom modal, but I will try this and see if it is better than my idea.

Comment: Slavaco, Please check this link also it might provide you the solution your are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164469/ios-mapkit-custom-callout

Comment: Yes, i need something like that, like I said in my question. I need to show my custom view in didSelectAnnotationView and not to show the callout.